# Thinkpad fn-keys only working after suspend

Tags: linux, suspend, thinkpad

recently I bought a nice lenovo thinkpad E14 (with AMD). Installation of Manjaro MATE went pretty flawless and everything is running pretty smoothly.
However the fn keys are not working as expected:

working:

```
fn + space is controling keyboard backlight
fn + Esc is enabling FnLock, although the status LED is not enabled/disabled
```

not working

```
all fn keys from F1 to F12 have no effect
```

When trying to edit a shortcut (e.g. volume up) in MATE keyboard shortcuts it is immediately set to "Wake up" when pressing the fn key (it is handled as an usual button).

I would really appreciate when owners of an E14 could let me know when they solved the issue or any other general help.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** fn-keys are working after suspend

**EDIT 2**:

```bsh
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
nls_utf8               16384  1
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_seq                86016  7 snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
isofs                  49152  1
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  1
xt_state               16384  0
xt_conntrack           16384  1
ipt_REJECT             16384  2
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
iptable_filter         16384  1
xt_tcpudp              20480  4
nf_nat_h323            24576  0
nf_conntrack_h323      86016  1 nf_nat_h323
nf_nat_pptp            20480  0
nf_conntrack_pptp      20480  1 nf_nat_pptp
nf_nat_tftp            16384  0
nf_conntrack_tftp      20480  1 nf_nat_tftp
nf_nat_sip             20480  0
nf_conntrack_sip       40960  1 nf_nat_sip
nf_nat_irc             20480  0
nf_conntrack_irc       20480  1 nf_nat_irc
nf_nat_ftp             20480  0
nf_conntrack_ftp       24576  1 nf_nat_ftp
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat                 53248  8 nf_nat_irc,nf_nat_ftp,nf_nat_tftp,nf_nat_pptp,nf_nat_h323,iptable_nat,xt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_sip
nf_conntrack          176128  16 xt_conntrack,nf_nat_irc,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_tftp,nf_nat_ftp,xt_state,nf_conntrack_pptp,nf_nat_tftp,nf_conntrack_sip,nf_conntrack_h323,nf_nat_pptp,nf_conntrack_irc,nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_nat_h323,xt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_sip
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
libcrc32c              16384  2 nf_conntrack,nf_nat
fuse                  143360  5
uvcvideo              114688  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
hid_generic            16384  0
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       57344  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
uas                    32768  0
usbhid                 65536  0
usb_storage            77824  3 uas
videodev              274432  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
hid                   143360  2 usbhid,hid_generic
mc                     61440  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
btusb                  65536  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  20480  1 btusb
btintel                32768  1 btusb
bluetooth             716800  5 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
joydev                 28672  0
mousedev               24576  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
kvm_amd               114688  0
kvm                   839680  1 kvm_amd
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           368640  0
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
pcspkr                 16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
psmouse               184320  0
amdgpu               5742592  5
k10temp                16384  0
sp5100_tco             20480  0
i2c_piix4              28672  0
snd_pci_acp3x          20480  0
iwlmvm                462848  0
mac80211             1040384  1 iwlmvm
snd_hda_codec_realtek   135168  1
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
gpu_sched              40960  1 amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
ttm                   118784  1 amdgpu
iwlwifi               393216  1 iwlmvm
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
nls_cp437              20480  1
snd_hda_intel          53248  4
vfat                   24576  1
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
fat                    86016  1 vfat
snd_hda_codec         167936  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
drm_kms_helper        253952  1 amdgpu
cfg80211              897024  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
snd_hda_core          106496  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
r8169                  98304  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
cec                    69632  1 drm_kms_helper
thinkpad_acpi         114688  0
snd_pcm               147456  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
rc_core                61440  1 cec
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
realtek                24576  1
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,thinkpad_acpi
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_timer              45056  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ccp                   118784  1 kvm_amd
libphy                147456  2 r8169,realtek
rfkill                 28672  8 bluetooth,thinkpad_acpi,cfg80211
snd                   114688  21 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
battery                20480  1 thinkpad_acpi
ac                     16384  0
tpm_crb                20480  0
i2c_scmi               20480  0
tpm_tis                16384  0
tpm_tis_core           32768  1 tpm_tis
ucsi_acpi              16384  0
typec_ucsi             36864  1 ucsi_acpi
tpm                    77824  3 tpm_tis,tpm_crb,tpm_tis_core
typec                  53248  1 typec_ucsi
wmi                    36864  1 wmi_bmof
acpi_cpufreq           28672  0
rng_core               16384  2 ccp,tpm
pinctrl_amd            32768  0
evdev                  28672  18
mac_hid                16384  0
drm                   581632  6 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,ttm
uinput                 20480  0
sg                     40960  0
crypto_user            16384  0
agpgart                53248  2 ttm,drm
ip_tables              36864  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               53248  7 xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_state,xt_tcpudp,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,xt_MASQUERADE
ext4                  798720  2
crc32c_generic         16384  0
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  139264  1 ext4
serio_raw              20480  0
atkbd                  36864  0
libps2                 20480  2 atkbd,psmouse
crc32c_intel           24576  5
xhci_pci               20480  0
xhci_hcd              286720  1 xhci_pci
i8042                  32768  0
serio                  28672  6 serio_raw,atkbd,psmouse,i8042
```

**EDIT 3 - SOLUTION:**

**Here is a full guide for Linux on Thinkpad E14 with a workaround for fn issues (suspend is required) https://rd.nz/2020/10/installing-ubuntu-linux-on-the-lenovo-thinkpad-e14-gen-2-amd**

Answer (score 1):

Add lsmod please. I had same issue on ideapad. Solution was blacklist thinkpad driver. Generic acpi driver works well.

To blacklist a kernel module, edit the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file and add a line that says "blacklist ".

```
blacklist thinkpad_acpi
```

Comment: thinkpad_acpi is loaded.

Comment: Blacklist it. This module is laggy

Comment: Once suspended with module thinkpad_acpi activated everything runs seamlessly. Same with thinkpad_acpi blacklisted, except that the keyboard status LED's are not working anymore.

Comment: with thinkpad_acpi blacklisted FN keys works or not? I dont looked at status LEDs on (my case) ideapad, and has no feedback from employees about it. I think  thinkpad_acpi driver needed  for this LEDs but break keyboard.

Comment: Some fn-keys are working with thinkpad_acpi blacklisted, some don't, Status LED's do not work. So thinkpad_acpi is better, ALL function keys work after suspen and status LED's do work, too.