# ThinkPad special keys not working

Tags: linux, keyboard, thinkpad

I recently purchased a new ThinkPad E14 Gen2 and I have installed both Windows 10 and Manjaro (i3 edition).

However, the special keys along the top row (mute, decrease and increase volume, toggle microphone, decrease and increase brightness, etc.) works in Windows, but not in Manjaro.

They do not even register with `showkey`, `xev`, `evtest` or anything else I have tried.

However, after suspending the keys start working as expected.

Comment: if it works after the suspend mode I think it is just ran at bad time-sequence so the question is : Is that you who implemented fn keys support ? (if so dignostic from your changes) If it comes with the distrib, it is a more or less known issue/bug that may have answer googling for it :) (from the model or family thinkpad keywords for research)

Comment: No, I did not implement the support for the keys. I actually found someone else that has the same problem on the same laptop (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602355/thinkpad-fn-keys-only-working-after-suspend), but he has not solved it either.
What do you mean by "ran at bad time-sequence"?