# Thinkpad Fn keys randomly stop working

Tags: linux, thinkpad, acpid

Running void linux on a Thinkpad E15 with KDE. Sometimes, my Fn keys (F1 to F12) stop working. What's interesting is that the FnLock and Fn+Space to toggle keyboard backlight work normally. Just like in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602355/thinkpad-fn-keys-only-working-after-suspend), but the solution didn't work for me. I tried enabling the acpid service (presumably the generic one, different from thinkpad_acpi), and that fixed the F1-F12 keys, but the power button started behaving differently. Previously, it would open the KDE logout menu, but now it turns the laptop straight off, which is not what I want.

lsmod outputs this for `thinkpad_acpi`, suggesting it's not used:
`thinkpad_acpi         200704  0`

Any ideas about what might be causing this issue?